# Setting default value for mat-select where my selection uses a function?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am new to Angular and am running into what im sure is a simple solution.

So I am trying to set a default value for my mat-select to be my 'Active' option. On selection, I call this function that will filter a table for me. However, I am having trouble using [(value)] or ngModel, as they seem to only accept variables instead of a function?

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline"
                class="detail-filter-menu">
  <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="true" (selectionChange)="this.filterService.applyFilter($event.value, dataSource)">
    <mat-option value="true">Active</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="false">Inactive</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="all">All</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Is there a way to use ngModel or something else in order to achieve a default selection?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the default value via a function you can do it like this:

Template Code

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
  <mat-select [value]="myFunction()" (selectionChange)="changed($event.value)">
    <mat-option value="active">Active</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="inactive">Inactive</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="all">All</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Component Code

```
myFunction() {
  return 'active';
}
```

You could also just set it without a function like so:

```
<mat-select [value]="'active'">
```

> Check out the
>   [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-kshtke?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).